# MySQL Stored functions and php

Tags: php, mysql, function

So i have this query to fetch all posts

```
select id, title 
from posts 
where type = 'article'
```

and i have a stored function that calculate the total of views and return the result

i know i can execute it like

```
select totalView(id)
```

but how can i merge the two queries to return all posts with the total view of each post

maybe something like

```
select id, title, totalView(id) as total 
from posts 
where type = 'article'
```

Thank you.

Comment: please show the totalView function

Comment: The example you have given **is** the answer to the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as total, id, title from posts where type = 'article'
```

EDIT : It will count all the rows of $id

```
select count(*) as total, id, title from posts where type = 'article' AND id = $id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but totalView is a stored function that  takes id of a post as an argument and returns total views.